# Is it possible to have a lookup column that points to a different site?

Tags: 2007, lookup-column

Is it possible to have a `Lookup` column that points to a different SharePoint site, hosted on the same SharePoint server?

Comment: Do you use WSS or SharePoint Server? Standard or Enterprise? 2007 or 2010?

Comment: @AlexPoint WSS I believe.  I know it's 2007 and Enterprise (sortof).

Answer (score 2):

A different site yes. A different site collection no. Then you'd need to create your own custom field type. Going to another webapp is another thing altogether (security wise it can be tricky). 
1 option could be to move your column to managed metadata if you are using SP2010, or use the BCS.

Comment: Same site collection, different site.  How would I do it?

Comment: By creating a site column in the root site of the site collection, include that in the content types it's needed

Answer (score 1):

If you create your lookup column as a Site column, then you can use it in all lists and child sites below that site.

Therefore, if you create a lookup at the site collection root, you will be able to use it everywhere in that site collection.

Sadly, there is no easy way of doing a lookup across site collection boundaries.